# Opening Connections to a DB

Tags: ms-access

My DB has multiple frontends and 1 backend.  It is not as fast as I would like it to be as it is a POS system for my restaurant.  My program makes many calls to the database as it's all dynamic.  Order screens call the db for menu items.  Menu items have modifiers or choices that go with them.  In every routine that calls the database which I'm making constantly.  I just want to know if I'm doing this the right way.  The DB has 50 + tables.  It is normalized.  It has 50 + forms. one customer order with just a couple of menu items and sides may make over 100 calls to the DB to get the menu and to save the order.
This is part of 1 sub from frmItemOrderDetails

```
Private Sub DisplayItemModifierSetButtons(intModifierSetPage As Integer)
    On Error GoTo HandleErrors

    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset: Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection: Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection: Dim sSql As String
```

Here is where we will fill the Menu Item Modifier Set buttons. Get their properties and their sort order.

```
   sSql = "SELECT tblMenuItemModifierSets.Modifier_set_id, tblModifierSets.Min_allowed,       tblModifierSets.Set_has_defaults, tblModifierSets.Items_are_passthrough,     tblModifierSets.Max_allowed, tblModifierSets.Mods_are_included, tblModifierSets.Screen_name, tblMenuItemModifierSets.Menu_item_id, tblModifierSets.Modifier_set_button_color, tblMenuItemModifierSets.Display_sort, tblModifierSets.Active " & _
            "FROM tblModifierSets INNER JOIN tblMenuItemModifierSets ON tblModifierSets.Modifier_set_id = tblMenuItemModifierSets.Modifier_set_id " & _
            "WHERE (((tblMenuItemModifierSets.Menu_item_id) = " & lMenuItem_id_m & ") And ((tblModifierSets.Active) = True)) " & _
            "ORDER BY tblMenuItemModifierSets.Display_sort;"
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False: rst.Open sSql, cnn, adOpenStatic
```

Things are done in here for setting up the buttons and assigning the Modifier_set_id to the tag on the command button so that I know what to do when it is pressed.
At the end of each sub, I close it all down.

```
ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not rst.State = adStateClosed Then rst.Close
    If Not cnn.State = adStateClosed Then cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing: Set cnn = Nothing: DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Set objModSetBtnLabel = Nothing: Set objModSetBtnImage = Nothing: Set objRequiredLabel = Nothing
    Exit Sub
HandleErrors:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & "In " & Me.Name & ".DisplayItemModifierSetButtons!" & vbNewLine & "Error Number: " & Err.Number
    Resume ExitHere
 End Sub
```

My question is, do you open and close the db constantly like this.
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset: Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection: Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Or is there a way to open the connection and then reuse it throughout the whole module and then close it at the end?  Seems like I'm doing a lot of things over and over again.  I've written a very extensive program that took several years, but I'm not a professional programmer.

Comment: What are the frontends built with? Is that VBA code? Since you show `CurrentProject.Connection` my guess is you have Access frontend with linked tables. You are use ADO instead of DAO recordset. Connection code is not necessary to open DAO recordsets.

Comment: Aside from that, it is considered good practice to unload objects at end of procedure although Access should do that by default. However, yes, can declare a connection globally and leave the connection in place as long as app is open. I am not sure if that would improve or hinder performance.

Comment: Everything is built with VBA.  There is a frontend and a backend.  I use ADODB everywhere.  SOmetimes when reloading an order screen because a customer has changed his mind, the Build screen routine will call the database up to 30 times to see if each  particular button should be set to selected.  I think I have way too many db calls.

Comment: If you want to use ADODB recordsets, then you have to use connection. Whether or not you declare and set with each procedure or use a global variable probably doesn't matter. However, since you use CurrentProject for the connection, I expect you have linked tables. Data is already available with those table links. What exactly do you do with those recordsets?